# Postgresql with python psycopg DataError: integer out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a line of code thate give me this error: `DataError: integer out of range`

The line of code is this :

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Users_Chat (Chat, User, Name, Id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (chat_version, user_id, name_user, 0, ))
```

I have created the table and columns with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE Users_Chat (Chat INT, User INT, Name TEXT, Id INT);
```

Comment: Extra comma at the end?

Comment: no, this not the problem, i tryed also without the comma and space at the end

Comment: what values do you have for chat_version, user_id, name_user?

Comment: is this inside a function and you pass those values?  because postgress is  expecting numbers, and probably you are passing something else.

Comment: oh, in chat_version is a number but start with a `-` is possible for this? I  worked only with sqlite and it worked with him. Like this `-1234`

Comment: yes, you want to remove 'dash' or convert you type to 'Strings'

Comment: for convert to strings what do you mean? in the code like this `new = str(chat_version)` or in the database i need to put in the table TEXT?. Because the `-` i must have it

Comment: if you want to keep 'dashes' in your chat version, you need to make changes in your database/table type.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Users_Chat (Chat, User, Name, Id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (chat_version, user_id, name_user, 0, ))
```

Expects only numeric/ingegers values according to doc.

> Python numeric objects int, long, float, Decimal are converted into a PostgreSQL numerical representation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html